# How do I reference a bootstrap scss variable using @use?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I have a simple stylesheet for a component in my site and I'm trying to pull in the `$zindex-fixed` variable, but my approach seems to have issues. Any help would be appreciated!

My stylesheet looks like:

```
@use "~bootstrap/scss/variables";

.playerBar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  min-width: 620px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: variables.$zindex-fixed;
  background: #1e1e1e;
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
SassError: Undefined mixin.
    ╷
307 │ @include _assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");
    │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss 307:1  @use
```

This is using Bootstrap 5.0.0-beta1 with sass 1.30.0. Please let me know if I can provide more info to help diagnose!

Comment: Are you using Dart Sass?

Comment: Yes, version 1.30

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are [no current plans](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/discussions/32458) to support the sass module system in Bootstrap v5. For now, the solution is to use `@import` instead of `@use`:

```
@import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";

.playerBar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  min-width: 620px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: $zindex-fixed;
  background: #1e1e1e;
}
```

Comment: Mainly going off the disclaimer from the sass team discouraging the use of the @import rule: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import

Comment: Right, because they are phasing it out.

Comment: I might be bad at this, but whenever I use (at)import with bootstrap I get a fancy new copy of it's css in my webpacked output. The more imports, the more copies. (at)use is the only way I've found around this.

Comment: There is a tool made by the sass team to migrate the `@import` version to the `@use` version. They use Bootstrap as an example :) https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/migrator